# Trouble with JQuery calling webservices with parameters and getting data back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I have a JQuery template, and I want to call a webservice and populate the fields in it. The issues I am having are, I'm not sure how to pass parameters in my $.ajax call (ideally, I want to pass a dictionary so I can pass as many or few parameters as I want).

I tried `data: { Key : Value }` but get a 500 server error saying something about not a valid JSON primative.

Once the webservice is called, how can I get my data back in a JSON string that is compatible with a JQuery template? My webservices usually get a List and my jquery template works with a JSON object.

The problem is basically the format of data between client and server. Any ideas?

My webservice call works fine, it's simply a problem of JSON and data.

Edit: I have succeeded in calling the webservice with a dictionary, I am now trying to figure out how to get the data back. I'm getting a circular reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) from [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/js.html).

**Examples:**

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
};

var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviver);

var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
```